# Prove/Argue that X is a binomial random variable.

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-numbers

assume that an experiment is conducted and that the outcome is considered o be either success or a failure. Let `p` denote the probability of success. Define X to be 1 if the experiment is success and 0 if it is a failure. `X` is said to have a point binomial or a Bernoulli distribution with parameter p.

How do i argue that `X` is a binomial random variable with `n=1` and find density for `X` ?

Comment: A *Binomial Distribution*, $\mathcal{Bin}(n, p)$ , is that of the count of successes in a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli trials with success rate $p$. $~$; That is the definition of what it is that it is. $~$ So...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, then 
$$P(X= k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
But the only possible values of $X$ are $0$ or $1$ and $n= 1$, hence
$$P(X = k) = \binom{1}{k}p^k(1-p)^{1-k}.$$
Check that this has the same distribution (table) as a Bernoulli trial with probability $p$.

Comment: I'm still confused on how to get the density.

Comment: $X$ is not continuous, it has a pmf, not a pdf.